# Access function variables between friend classes

Tags: c++

Just wondering...how can I access the variable 'path' of ClassA function Open() from within another fucntion of class ClassB if both classes are declared 'friends'? I'm basically trying to populate a child window with info from the parent window when the child window is selected, although both windows have different classes.

ClassA.cpp:

```
void ClassA::Open() 
{ 
// Open Program Properties window 

ClassB dlg; 

dlg.DoModal(); 

CString path; 

path = m_DirTree.GetCurrentDir(); //Path specified by tree selection

}
```

ClassB.cpp:

```
void ClassB::Display(){

//HOW CAN I ACCESS 'path' HERE? 

SetDlgItemText(IDC_PATH, path); //Populate the edit box 

}
```

Thankyou for the replies...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass an A object by reference (or any other way to make the object visible to B::Display) and just excess it with '.' operator

```
void ClassB::Display(A &a){
    SetDlgItemText(IDC_PATH, a.path);
}
```

although you might want to consider exposing public set and get functions for these kind of variables

Answer (score 1):

With your current code you can't.

After the function `void ClassA::Open()` your `CString path;` will be destroyed.

You could save your `CString path;` as member variable.

Or you could add a variable of `CString` to your function `void ClassB::Display()`, which could result in this code:

```
void ClassA::Open(void) 
{ 
    // Open Program Properties window 
    ClassB dlg; 
    dlg.DoModal(); 

    CString path; 
    path = m_DirTree.GetCurrentDir(); //Path specified by tree selection
    m_classBMember.Display(path);
}


void ClassB::Display(CString &path)
{
    SetDlgItemText(IDC_PATH, path); //Populate the edit box
}
```

Comment: Thanks man.... however when I do as you have advised...I get the following error: 'Display' : overloaded member function not found in 'SecondDlg' which points to 'void ClassB::Display(CString &path){..}' Everything has been declared correctly in the header files...I think the & operator may be causing an issue with addressing..

Comment: `Everything has been declared correctly in the header files` it does not seem like it has been. Did you declare the function correctly ? Update your question or use pastebin if needed (with the declarations).